# How to update a variable that comes from a getter

Tags: c++, methods, overriding

I need my front method to be able to support doing something like this for my assignment. Its been 4 hours. I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried overloading the = operator but that doesn't seem to work.

```
vectD3.front() = '{';
vectD3.back() = '}';
```

basically I need that code to not throw an error when ran

here is my front and back methods

```
   public:T front()
   {
      if(currentSize > 0)
      {
         return array[0];
      }
      else
      {
         throw std::runtime_error("dynarray has no members");   
      }
   }
   public:T back()
   {
      if(currentSize > 0)
      {
         return array[currentSize-1];
      }
      else
      {
         throw std::runtime_error("dynarray has no members");
      }
   }
```

Thanks is advance

Comment: If it helps heres all the code

Comment: nvm wont let me...

Comment: Your methods should return a reference. If you don't know what a reference is, see the appropriately-named chapter in your C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return reference by your getter function. then you can modify it.
Something like this :

```
class A
{
public:
    A(char d1): data(d1) {}

    char& getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
private:
    char data;
};

int main()
{
    A a('a');
    std::cout << a.getData();//data = a
    a.getData() = 'b'; 
    std::cout << a.getData();//data = b

    return 0;
}
```